# This would be the vector field of $\langle \sin(y), \sin(x)\rangle$, would it not?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-fields

Vector field of what I *thought* was $\langle\sin(y),\sin(x)\rangle$ but apparently it's not:
[image: 1]

My instructor said "Try something simpler" but I think I've tried practically every combo of what would be considered "simpler" in the book.  The closest I got was $\langle xy,x^2\rangle$, but half the graph is wrong on that one.  I am at a loss.
I would appreciate any hints at all.

Comment: Notice that the $y$ component of the input gives the $x$ component of the output. Maybe you thought $<\sin (x), \sin (y)>$

Comment: It can't be $<sin(y), sin(x)>$ since the vectors seem to be unbounded.

Comment: What about $(y,x)$? Note that the magnitude seems to be proportional to $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin you're correct.
I could have sworn I tried <y,x> already, but I guess I didn't or I put it in wrong somehow.  Thanks for you're guys' help

Comment: Why don’t you post an answer (with explanation)?

Comment: If it's to scale, it's not $\langle y,x \rangle.$ The vector at $(4,4)$ would only be twice the length of the vector at $(2,2)$ if that were the function. But I guess it's too much to hope that an exercise that fails to provide actual numbers would pay attention to scale.